# On power series and differentiability; Hunter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, proof-explanation, power-series

I am reading these [lecture notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/intro_analysis_pdf/intro_analysis.html) by Hunter and have a question about a proof concerning the differentiability of a function which can be written as a power series. The results relevant to understanding the below theorem and proof is that if

1. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}(x-c)^{n}$ has radius of convergence $R$,
   then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_{n}(x-c)^{n-1}$ also has radius of
   convergence $R$ (let's call this Theorem 1).
2. $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}(x-c)^{n}$ has radius of convergence $R$,
   then it converges uniformly on $|x-c|\leq\rho$ for any $0\leq
   \rho<R$ (let's call this Theorem 2).
3. $(f_n)$ is a sequence of differentiable functions $f_n:
   (a,b)\to\mathbb R$ such that $f_n\to f$ pointwise and $f_n'\to g$
   uniformly for some $f,g : (a,b)\to\mathbb R$, then $f$ is
   differentiable on $(a,b)$ and $f'=g$ (let's call this Theorem 3).

Then consider the following theorem and proof:

> **Theorem 10.21.** Suppose that the power series
> $$
> f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}(x-c)^{n} \quad \text { for }|x-c|<R
> $$
> has radius of convergence $R>0$ and sum $f$. Then $f$ is differentiable in $|x-c|<R$ and
> $$
> f^{\prime}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_{n}(x-c)^{n-1} \quad \text { for }|x-c|<R .
> $$

> **Proof.** The term-by-term differentiated power series converges in $|x-c|<R$ [by Theorem 1]. We denote its sum by
> $$
> g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_{n}(x-c)^{n-1} .
> $$
> Let $0<\rho<R$. Then [by Theorem 2] the power series for $f$ and $g$ both converge uniformly in $|x-c|<\rho$. Applying [Theorem 3] to their partial sums, we conclude that $f$ is differentiable in $|x-c|<\rho$ and $f^{\prime}=g$. Since this holds for every $0 \leq \rho<R$, it follows that $f$ is differentiable in $|x-c|<R$ and $f^{\prime}=g$, which proves the result.

For the life of me, I can not figure out why the author has written $0 \leq \rho<R$ in the last sentence. Why the non-strict inequality? The author writes at the beginning of the paragraph that "Let $0 < \rho<R$..." and everything makes sense up to the last sentence. Is this a typo or does is it actually make sense for $\rho$ to equal $0$?

Comment: It is a typo. For $\rho = 0$ you do not get an open interval on which the partial sums live.

Comment: Thank you for checking! This is what I thought. So $0 < \rho<R$ it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be $0<\rho<R$. If $\rho=0$, then the partial sums are defined nowhere.